# Get array values from named index JS

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I have a JS variable that receive a serialized C# List with JavaScriptSerializer.

The string passed to the JS variable after serialization is like this :

```
{"Date":"April 2017 - April 2017","Source":"Foo","Type":"Bar","Value":14}{"Date":"April 2017 - April 2017","Source":"Foo","Type":"Bar","Value":14}
```

I would like to put all the "Values" in an array x and all the "Date" in an array y.

When i do `x: source["Date"]` and `y: source["Value"]`, x and y stay empty.

Why is that ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, at first glance, I expect the json format to be [{},{},{}] (array of objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Json is not properly formatted, however if you correct it into the proper Json format you can use JavaScript map to accomplish what you need.

```
let arr = '[{"Date":"April 2017 - April 2017","Source":"Foo","Type":"Bar","Value":14},
          {"Date":"April 2017 - April 2017","Source":"Foo","Type":"Bar","Value":14}]';

let source = JSON.parse(arr);

let x = source.map(x=> x.Date);
let y = source.map(x=> x.Value);

console.log(x);
//[ 'April 2017 - April 2017', 'April 2017 - April 2017' ]

console.log(y);
//[ 14, 14 ]
```

Comment: I have ECMAScript 5 and not ECMAScript 2015, what would this expression do in ECMAScript 5 ? (i'm newbie to js...)

Comment: Just replace let with var. Map should work with es5.

Comment: **var x = source.map( function(x){  return x.Date;  }** you can learn more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control

Comment: Yes, i found it like a big boy, and learnt about arrowed function in the process :) Thank you